# Highlight text one character at a time in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer

Internet Explorer is doing that annoying thing that Word also does: it tries to select more text than you are highlighting with the mouse. For example, in the text below, selecting the first 4 characters actually selects 5.

MAX([Booking date])

I know this annoying feature can be turned off in Word, but what about IE? I can't find anything.

My usual solution would be to not use IE but I'm using a SharePoint site which doesn't work properly in other browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Caret Browsing to get precise text selection. Hit <kbd>F7</kbd> to turn it on, and then use the <kbd>Shift</kbd> and arrow keys to select your desired text.

Also, while this doesn't seem to work for your example above, usually if you move the mouse back a bit after the selection expands to a whole word, and then continue on, it will revert back to where your selection had actually started.

Comment: Thanks, I can't (yet) see any downside of having caret browsing on permanently, so I'll switch that on in Internet Tools > Advanced. Better than nothing!